# Java EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR

Tags: java

I tried to check the jdk version in cmd by typing `javac -version` when i hit enter i got this

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR (0xc0000006) at pc=0x5d002e63, pid=3872, tid=4900
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xd2e63]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x013bbc00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=4900, stack(0x01840000,0x01890000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000006

Error accessing class data sharing archive. Mapped file inaccessible during execution,  possible disk/network problem.

Registers:
EAX=0x0000000d, EBX=0x00000002, ECX=0x140f82e0, EDX=0x8dc9649f
ESP=0x0188a908, EBP=0x0188a908, ESI=0x1549c29c, EDI=0x140f82e0
EIP=0x5d002e63, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0188a908)
0x0188a908:   0188a928 5cf7b6ca 15147230 0000000d
0x0188a918:   0000000d 8dc9649f 15147230 012636f8
0x0188a928:   0188a94c 5cf7b76c 000047ac 15147230
0x0188a938:   0000000d 8dc9649f 0188add4 00000052
0x0188a948:   0000000d 0188aa30 5cf63147 15147230
0x0188a958:   0000000d 0188a980 0188add4 013bbc00
0x0188a968:   1449f898 0701e400 00fce500 00000002
0x0188a978:   00000000 0188af24 8dc9649f 00000002 

Instructions: (pc=0x5d002e63)
0x5d002e43:   e8 48 c6 fc ff 8b c8 8b 46 04 83 c4 14 f7 d8 1b
0x5d002e53:   c0 f7 d0 23 c1 5e 5d c3 cc cc cc cc cc 55 8b ec
0x5d002e63:   0f b7 01 3b 45 0c 74 06 32 c0 5d c2 08 00 56 85
0x5d002e73:   c0 7e 19 8b 75 08 8d a4 24 00 00 00 00 8a 54 30 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x0000000d is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000002 is an unknown value
ECX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000006]

Stack: [0x01840000,0x01890000],  sp=0x0188a908,  free space=298k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xd2e63]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4b6ca]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4b76c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x33147]
V  [jvm.dll+0x33463]
V  [jvm.dll+0x39165]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4fa17]
V  [jvm.dll+0x106ab9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x106c8b]
C  [java.dll+0x1c7d]
C  0x02000000

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;+27
j  java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/CodeSource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+12
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+138
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Ljava/net/URLClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class;+43
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+13
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+70
j  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+81
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;+27
j  java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/CodeSource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+12
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+138
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Ljava/net/URLClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class;+43
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+13
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+70
j  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+81
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;+27
j  java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/CodeSource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+12
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+138
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Ljava/net/URLClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class;+43
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+13
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+70
j  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+81
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option$2.matches(Ljava/lang/String;)Z+12
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.processArgs([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Collection;+74
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/Context;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/List;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/main/Main$Result;+146
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile([Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/Context;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/List;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/main/Main$Result;+7
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile([Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/Context;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/main/Main$Result;+7
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile([Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/main/Main$Result;+15
j  com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile([Ljava/lang/String;)I+12
j  com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x01325c00 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5680, stack(0x15030000,0x15080000)]
  0x012f7c00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5336, stack(0x017e0000,0x01830000)]
  0x012f6000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3484, stack(0x14fe0000,0x15030000)]
  0x012f3000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5564, stack(0x14ec0000,0x14f10000)]
  0x012e1000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3164, stack(0x14e30000,0x14e80000)]
  0x01283c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4028, stack(0x14770000,0x147c0000)]
=>0x013bbc00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=4900, stack(0x01840000,0x01890000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0127f800 VMThread [stack: 0x146d0000,0x14720000] [id=1024]
  0x01330400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x14f80000,0x14fd0000] [id=3056]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 def new generation   total 2432K, used 316K [0x03c00000, 0x03ea0000, 0x09150000)
  eden space 2176K,   2% used [0x03c00000, 0x03c0f1e8, 0x03e20000)
  from space 256K, 100% used [0x03e60000, 0x03ea0000, 0x03ea0000)
  to   space 256K,   0% used [0x03e20000, 0x03e20000, 0x03e60000)
 tenured generation   total 5504K, used 169K [0x09150000, 0x096b0000, 0x13c00000)
   the space 5504K,   3% used [0x09150000, 0x0917a780, 0x0917a800, 0x096b0000)
 Metaspace       used 547K, capacity 2628K, committed 2752K, reserved 4480K

Card table byte_map: [0x01740000,0x017d0000] byte_map_base: 0x01722000

Polling page: 0x00250000

CodeCache: size=32768Kb used=726Kb max_used=726Kb free=32041Kb
 bounds [0x01bd0000, 0x01c88000, 0x03bd0000]
 total_blobs=178 nmethods=40 adapters=70
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.219 Thread 0x012f7c00   36  s!         sun.misc.URLClassPath::getLoader (197 bytes)
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x012f7c00 nmethod 36 0x01c81a88 code [0x01c81ce0, 0x01c82e0c]
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x012f7c00   37             java.lang.String::<init> (82 bytes)
Event: 0.221 Thread 0x012f7c00 nmethod 37 0x01c83f88 code [0x01c840d0, 0x01c842e0]
Event: 0.221 Thread 0x012f7c00   38  s          sun.misc.URLClassPath::getNextLoader (88 bytes)
Event: 0.221 Thread 0x012f7c00 nmethod 38 0x01c84508 code [0x01c84650, 0x01c84a44]
Event: 0.221 Thread 0x012f7c00   39             sun.misc.URLClassPath::getResource (83 bytes)
Event: 0.221 Thread 0x012f7c00 nmethod 39 0x01c84d88 code [0x01c84eb0, 0x01c84fd4]
Event: 0.224 Thread 0x012f7c00   40   !         sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader::getResource (85 bytes)
Event: 0.229 Thread 0x012f7c00 nmethod 40 0x01c850c8 code [0x01c85240, 0x01c856b4]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 0.224 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 2432K, used 2176K [0x03c00000, 0x03ea0000, 0x09150000)
  eden space 2176K, 100% used [0x03c00000, 0x03e20000, 0x03e20000)
  from space 256K,   0% used [0x03e20000, 0x03e20000, 0x03e60000)
  to   space 256K,   0% used [0x03e60000, 0x03e60000, 0x03ea0000)
 tenured generation   total 5504K, used 0K [0x09150000, 0x096b0000, 0x13c00000)
   the space 5504K,   0% used [0x09150000, 0x09150000, 0x09150200, 0x096b0000)
 Metaspace       used 544K, capacity 2628K, committed 2752K, reserved 4480K
Event: 0.228 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 2432K, used 256K [0x03c00000, 0x03ea0000, 0x09150000)
  eden space 2176K,   0% used [0x03c00000, 0x03c00000, 0x03e20000)
  from space 256K, 100% used [0x03e60000, 0x03ea0000, 0x03ea0000)
  to   space 256K,   0% used [0x03e20000, 0x03e20000, 0x03e60000)
 tenured generation   total 5504K, used 169K [0x09150000, 0x096b0000, 0x13c00000)
   the space 5504K,   3% used [0x09150000, 0x0917a780, 0x0917a800, 0x096b0000)
 Metaspace       used 544K, capacity 2628K, committed 2752K, reserved 4480K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (8 events):
Event: 0.056 Thread 0x013bbc00 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x03c079d8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u91\6644\hotspot\src\share\vÄ½zwÚy¬?
Event: 0.056 Thread 0x013bbc00 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x03c07ca8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u91\6644\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, l4[}`$ÄÉ?
Event: 0.201 Thread 0x013bbc00 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x03d520e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u91\6644\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.201 Thread 0x013bbc00 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x03d524c0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u91\6644\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.202 Thread 0x013bbc00 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x03d560d0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u91\6644\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.202 Thread 0x013bbc00 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x03d564b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u91\6644\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.206 Thread 0x013bbc00 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x03d8b0d8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u91\6644\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.206 Thread 0x013bbc00 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x03d8b4b8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u91\6644\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.224 loading class com/sun/tools/doclint/DocLint$BadArgs
Event: 0.224 loading class com/sun/tools/doclint/DocLint$BadArgs done
Event: 0.224 loading class com/sun/tools/doclint/DocLint$DeclScanner
Event: 0.224 loading class com/sun/tools/doclint/DocLint$DeclScanner done
Event: 0.224 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 0.228 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 0.228 loading class com/sun/source/util/TreePathScanner
Event: 0.228 loading class com/sun/source/util/TreePathScanner done
Event: 0.228 loading class com/sun/source/util/TreeScanner
Event: 0.228 loading class com/sun/source/util/TreeScanner done


Dynamic libraries:
0x01230000 - 0x01236000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac.exe
0x76df0000 - 0x76f32000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x76bb0000 - 0x76c85000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x74f80000 - 0x74fcb000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x6a070000 - 0x6a09b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\jli.dll
0x756b0000 - 0x75751000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76a50000 - 0x76afc000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x75a00000 - 0x75a19000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x76b00000 - 0x76ba2000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x73d10000 - 0x73eae000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_41e855142bd5705d\COMCTL32.dll
0x76fe0000 - 0x7702e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x75b40000 - 0x75c09000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x757a0000 - 0x757aa000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76f40000 - 0x76fdd000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x76890000 - 0x768e7000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x69fb0000 - 0x6a06f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\MSVCR100.dll
0x75a90000 - 0x75aaf000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x768f0000 - 0x769bc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x69de0000 - 0x69e9f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x5cf30000 - 0x5d2fa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x6dd60000 - 0x6dd67000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x75760000 - 0x75795000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x75ab0000 - 0x75ab6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x707b0000 - 0x707e2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x742f0000 - 0x742f9000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x75a20000 - 0x75a25000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x71610000 - 0x7161c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x69f80000 - 0x69fa1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6ab20000 - 0x6ab33000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x75c40000 - 0x7688b000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x76c90000 - 0x76ded000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x74d60000 - 0x74d6b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x66af0000 - 0x66bdb000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Denv.class.path=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip -Dapplication.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91 -Xms8m 
java_command: com.sun.tools.javac.Main -version
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91/lib/tools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91/classes
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;E:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;E:\doxygen\bin
USERNAME=abc
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23392)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 37 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 1956984k(316744k free), swap 3913968k(1731388k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.91-b14) for windows-x86 JRE (1.8.0_91-b14), built on Apr  1 2016 01:01:28 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Fri Jun 02 16:11:31 2017

elapsed time: 4 seconds (0d 0h 0m 4s)
```

and whenever i type `javac` it shows the list as it should, also I can execute my programs from eclipse. I didn't tried from cmd.
Anyone having idea what this is?

Edit: it worked randomly after i repeatedly executed the command but it comes back.

Comment: [might the first comment on this bug report solve the problem?](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7020782)

Comment: Reinstall java you have old one http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a corrupted installation ("possible disk/network problem."), please reinstall your JRE/JDK and report back if that solved the issue.

Comment: now it is working i din't reinstalled it but executed `javac -version` and it magically worked, no idea how it happened!

Comment: @A.Joshi Your storage medium may have sporadic failures, I recommend backing up your data and running system diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

It looked fine for me in cmd on Windows.

```
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xd2e63]
```

Maybe your jvm.dll is corrupted.  You may want to try a reinstall.  From the error message you posted, your current version is:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there multiple JRE OR OS available in your system? This is crashing on particular version command checking. Finding it's root cause is difficult as there may be multiple resons for this.

Comment: yes i have multiple jre and using jre 1.8_0_131 and jdk 1.8.0_91 i am updating my jdk right now